# apt-get error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code while performing upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg

I Have an error while performing upgrade or installing any software in ubuntu 14.04.

Error :

```
apt-get error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error codeReading
 package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done   
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apport python-libxml2    
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.   
36 not fully installed or removed.   
Need to get 0 B/320 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.    
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

(Reading database ... 242426 files and directories currently installed.)    
Preparing to unpack .../apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.19_all.deb ...    
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63    
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^    
SyntaxError: invalid syntax    
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1    
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...    
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63
    except (IOError, OSError), e:
                             ^   
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.14.1-
0ubuntu3.19_all.deb (--unpack):    
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>   
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \    
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>   
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser   
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'  
dpkg: error while cleaning up:    
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1   
Preparing to unpack .../python-libxml2_2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb     
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63  
    except (IOError, OSError), e: 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax    
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1   
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...    
  File "/usr/bin/pyclean", line 63  
    except (IOError, OSError), e:  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax   
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-libxml2_2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb (--unpack):   
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1    
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>  
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser    
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'  
dpkg: error while cleaning up:    
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
Errors were encountered while processing:    
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.14.1-0ubuntu3.19_all.deb  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-libxml2_2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb   
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Thanks in advance
                             ^

Comment: The error message looks like you have an older Python version which does not support this `except` syntax.  That should simply not be possible if your Ubuntu really is an up-to-date 14.04.  But anyhow, this is not a programming question, and you do not supply enough details to properly diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the error

This error has occurred while I was trying to install scikit-learn which only works with python3. So, I've installed python3 and made it as default.

In general, ubuntu have some dependencies with python2 and this dpkg error occurred as a result of making python3 as default. So, I rectified the problem by creating links.

Comment: This is [how to set python 3 as default interpreter](http://askubuntu.com/a/590030/656435)